# Confusion about Go back N ARQ

Tags: networking

[Go-Back-N window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444055/go-back-n-window-size)

In the second image on the above Page's answer, what will happen after all the three ACKs have been lost? Won't the system get stuck? Sender will keep sending frames 0,1,2 but since the receiver expects frame 3, it will not send an ACK. It will be silent forever, and the sender will keep sending frames 0,1,2 forever, after timeouts. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is straight No.

Here when that timeout timer timeouts, as happened in this case since acks got lost. Thus the sender will retransmit the data. But you see, the receiver will again send ack because this is what happens in Go-Back-N if ack gets lost. Also, do note that the receiver will discard the packets since it got it before only. Now when the sender will get the ack, it will send again as per win size.